# What is the computational complexity to compute the integral numerically?

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, computational-complexity

Given $$\int_{\Delta}\frac{P_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}{P_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}$$ where $P_i$ is polynomial(that is $P_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n), P_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ are polynomial) whose coefficients are over $\mathbb{Q}$,$\Delta$ is the domain defined by polynomial inequality with coefficients  over $\mathbb{Q}$,What is the computational complexity to compute the integral numerically? Especialy in the term of polynomials and the polynomials inequality defining the domain.

Comment: Even in the one variable case, I suspect that this strongly depends on whether the roots of $P_2$ lie close to $\Delta$.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2083

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00211-009-0284-9

Comment: Crucially, the first paper cited by @SteveHuntsman, "How to integrate a polynomial over a simplex" by Baldoni, Berline, De Loera, Köppe and Vergne focuses on polynomials.  For rational functions, we end up having to approximate $\log$ or $\arctan$ and don't only get rational numbers.  An instructive example could be $\int_0^1 P(x) / (x + 1) \mathrm{d}x = a \log 2 + b$.  The rational numbers $a$ and $b$ are cheap to compute from the coefficients of $P$, but if $-b/a\simeq\log 2$ only a specifically Taylored algorithm would approximate $a\log 2 + b$ efficiently.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman, thank you for the reference.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch, thank you for your comments. I am wondering whether the antiderivative of the integrand is relevant to the complexity. In fact, your suspicion may be relating the kind of anti-derivative.

Comment: Actually, I have been suspecting that there exists a polynomial time complexity algorithm, but one paper Steve give in the comment has claims that the computational complexity is $NP-$hard. I have to carefully read the article or think about the question again.